# textbox sends enter key for each number entered

Tags: c#-4.0

Im using a textbox to accept barcode input and then the enter key to do stuff with that input. But its sending the enter key once for each number entered. Is there a way to have the enter key sent only once? Or maybe supress the other enters?

```
private void txtBscanned_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       this.txtBscanned.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.OnKeyDownHandler);
    }
   private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {

                MessageBox.Show(txtBscanned.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What will trigger the the "once" you are talking about?

Comment: I put 13 numbers then an enter at the end.  But the messagebox is coming up 13 times.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning a keydown event on the textbox itself? You should assign the event on the constructor or using the designer.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtBscanned.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.OnKeyDownHandler);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.

Comment: Mark it as an answer if it fixed your problem